# Django: Why does a UserProfile Admin attribute show every object in the database upon creation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

When a new UserProfile is created with this model, the follower, following, and likes fields automatically get filled up with all the objects in the database. Why?

Here is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank= True, null=True)  
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Article, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "user Profiles"
```

Here is the view:

```
class Signup(View):
    template_name = "auth/signup.html"
    form = UserCreationForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('home_page'))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): #correct this
            new_user = form.save()
            #now create a UserProfile instance and save it
            new_UserProfile = UserProfile(user=new_user)
            new_UserProfile.save()
            #now log the user in
            new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect(reverse('home_page'))
        else:
            #failure for some reason
            form = UserCreationForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

Admin:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user',)
    list_display_links = ('user',)


admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Screen shot:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I just realized that when querying the UserProfiles, they bring back empty lists:

```
>>> k.following.all()
[]
>>> k.likes.all()
[]
```

Why does the admin show every object in the database? These object are not assigned to them are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're misunderstanding what those boxes are showing you. You have nothing selected, but they show you all objects available for selection.

Comment: Would it be possible change that? Or is it better left this way?